# OrderByDescending() per MSDN, what on earth does this mean?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, msdn

Can someone please help be take apart the elements here and help me understand what they are?

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderByDescending<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector
)
```

What is TSource and TKey? What is a keySelector? What the heck is an IOrderedEnumerable?

What does Func<> do??

Why is MSDN so cryptic?

Comment: Didn't you post an incredibly similar question already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827209/how-did-you-learn-master-c-linq-to-sql

Comment: no but while I was writing that question I decided to ask this one to get specifics on this thing, that other question was about learning LINQ to SQL, this one is about this specific block of code.

Comment: I guess you should learn generic classes as well as lambda expressions. MSDN won't seem cryptic anymore.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Break Down

- TSource: This is the type of elements in the collection which need to be ordered
- TKey: The type key by which the elements are ordered.
- `Func<TSource,TKey>`: Delegate which will return a key for a given element in the collection

This function is essentially a sorting function.  As such it needs a way to compare the elements in the collection.  This particular method assumes that for a given object there is a corresponding key value by which they can be sorted.

Take for example the following class Student

```
class Student { 
  string Name { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

If I wanted to sort a collection of `Student` instances by their name I could do the following

```
IEnumerable<Student> col = GetTheStudents();
var ordered = col.OrderByDescending( x => x.Name );
```

In this case the values would be as follows

- TSource: `Student`
- TKey: `String`
- `Func<TSource,TKey>`: This is the passed in lambda expression `x => x.Name`

Comment: Great response, one more thing: I am having trouble understanding where you get x, or is x being declared right there? Why the 'equal to our greater than'?

Comment: Likewise what if you just put '=' or if you put '=<' (equal to or less than) ?

Comment: @Ryan, x is declared as a part of the lambda expression.  A more expanded form is the following: delegate (string x) { return x.Name;}

Answer (score 3):

I just wonder, what is exactly unclear on MSDN?
Here is the topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548916.aspx

And here are some answers to your questions from that topic:

> **Type Parameters**
>
> TSource - The type of the elements of source.
>
> TKey - The type of the key returned by keySelector.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> source - A sequence of values to order.
>
> keySelector - A function to extract a key from an element.
>
> comparer - An IComparer to compare keys.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> An IOrderedEnumerable whose elements are sorted in descending order according to a key.

Also, there are remarks and an example. What you posted here is just a signature of the method.

Comment: ok you're right, I was just being frustrated, I guess it's not MSDN that's cryptic to me it's the LINQ :)

Comment: I'd say it's not just LINQ. C# has changed a lot from 1.0 to 3.0. Probably, it will be good for you to just get a good book about C# 3.0 and read about generics, extension methods, lambda expressions, delegates, and yes, LINQ. Right now it seams that you simply cannot read new C# syntax.